# Removing the menu delay in Kickoff Application Launcher

Tags: kubuntu, kickoff

Is there any way to remove the menu delay in [Kickoff Application Launcher](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff)? I use Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4. By menu delay I mean the delay for opening submenus when the mouse hovers over a folder item.

E.g. on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate I remove it using [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/):

[image]